# Undelete this non-constructive question. I want to re-phrase the question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a question with title "Is this plausible that best Lanterns failed to beat Parallax and felt fear?" under `green-lantern` tag. It was first closed as non-constructive. Now, it has been deleted.

Please, un-delete that question. I want to re-phrase that it make it constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24668/is-this-plausible-that-best-lanterns-failed-to-beat-parallax-and-felt-fear) was automatically deleted after a month of inactivity because it was closed, had a negative score and no answer. Since you have pledged to edit it to make it reopenable, I've undeleted it.